# Как реализовать sql поиск по нескольким полям с учётом того, что запрос может содержать сразу два поля?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как реализовать sql поиск по нескольким полям?Пример работает не корректно

```
select id,name,surname from users WHERE name LIKE '%Роман%' OR surname LIKE '%Роман%'
```

Сейчас идёт поиск и ищем значение "Роман" по двум полям. Точно так же запрос "Ракзин" выводит фамилию....
но если ввести "Ракзин Роман", то так как поля нет- естественно ничего не выводится. Мне нужно сделать запрос, что данный вариант работал. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Если поля нет, значит надо создать его "виртуально":

```
select id,name,surname
  from users
 where surname+' '+name LIKE '%Ракзин Роман%'
    or name+' '+surname LIKE '%Ракзин Роман%'
```

Второе условие задано на случай, если имя введут первым ("Роман Ракзин"). Но предварительная обработка текста пользовательского запроса все равно не помешает, ибо текущий поиск ничего не найдет если между словами окажется два пробела.

Answer (score 0):

1. Разбить входную строку на слова и формировать запрос уже по ним.
2. Использовать механизм полнотекстового поиска с таблицей для индексации необходимых полей